# How to put h1 tag adjacent to logo?

Tags: html

I need to find a a way to put the h1 tag so that it aligns with my logo.

**HTML Code**:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
        RKS Public School
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
        <img src=
          "logo.PNG"
          alt="logo"
          align="left:50px"
          width=120,height="120">
    </body>
<html>
```

Comment: using `with` you mean aside of logo?

Comment: Remove all the `&nbsp;`. Instead of your img tag, try this: `<div><img src="logo.png" alt="logo" align="left:50px;" width=120 height=120><h1>Whatever</h1></div>`

Comment: @AlirezaHI yes.

Comment: pls go thrugh the basic https://www.w3schools.com/html/

Comment: @anoop yes I did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this is your desire result.

```css
.d-inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    RKS Public School
  </title>
</head>

<body>
  &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/120" alt="logo" align="left:50px" width=120, height="120">
  <h1 class="d-inline-block">Header Besides Image</h1>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: doesn't help. please help.

Comment: @Devansh did you run the code snippet? The header is just besides the image. This CSS style is needed  
.d-inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}